# Error shows while using SMTP sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have tried using SMTP sampler with the following details,

1. **server:** smtp.googlemail.com
2. **port:** 587
3. **Address from:** gmail account
4. **Address to:** gmail account
5. **checked Use Auth**
   check box and the required username and password of the from
   gmail account is given with the subject and message body.

But I'm facing the below sampler result,

***Response code: 500
Response message: Other MessagingException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.googlemail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect***

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you turned on this setting in your gmail? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm JMeter network connectivity by adding i.e. [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and opening a website which definitely exists, i.e. http://example.com

If you get the same "Connection refused" message - most probably you are sitting behind the corporate firewall and you will need to apply some extra configuration so JMeter would use your corporate proxy like:

```
jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password
```

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) guide for more information.

If you can send requests to Internet web sites and services successfully - double-check your SMTP Sampler configuration, maybe your config is missing an important setting, i.e. `Use StartTLS`

[image: JMeter SMTP Sampler]

Refer [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for comprehensive explanation and example configurations.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I tried as you mentioned. But still am facing the same issue. Even in log file it shows error like, Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -4. See log file fo
r details.